# How to handle when user return back to app without login from google using Google iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-plus

I am using Google-iOS SDK for login.How to know when user tries to authenticate to the google, but changes mind and without login returns back to app. Is there any method which gets invoked on this event on google ios sdk?

For facebook there is :

```
[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
```

which is called from `applicationDidBecomeActive` method of app delegate.

With Facebook-SDK if user returns to the app without signing in, the session gets closed.

Method named:

```
sessionStateChanged: state: error:
```

get called.

Is there anything like this in Google-SDK for iOS?